# when is it not performance practical to use persist() on a spark dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.3

While working on improving code performance as I had many jobs fail (aborted), I thought about using `persist()` function on Spark Dataframe whenever I need to use that same dataframe on many other operations. When doing it and following the jobs, stages in the Spark application UI, I felt like it's not really always optimal to do so, it depends on the number of partitions and the data size. I wasn't sure until I got the job aborted because of a fail in the persist stage.

I'm questioning **if the best practice of using `persist()` whenever many operations will be performed on the dataframe is always valid?** **If not, when it's not? how to judge?**

To be more concrete I will present my code and the details of the aborted job:

```
#create a dataframe from another one df_transf_1 on which I made a lot of transformations but no actions
spark_df = df_transf_1.select('user_id', 'product_id').dropDuplicates()
#persist
spark_df.persist()
products_df = spark_df[['product_id']].distinct()
df_products_indexed = products_df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.product_id).zipWithIndex().toDF(['product_id', 'product_index'])
```

You may ask why I persisted `spark_df`?
It's because I'm going to use it multiple of times like with `products_df` and also in `joins` (e.g: `spark_df = spark_df.join(df_products_indexed,"product_id")`

[image: Job stages]

Details of fail reason in Stage 3:

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 40458 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 40458.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 60778, xx.xx.yyyy.com, executor 91): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 91 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
>   Driver stacktrace:

The size of the input data (**4 TB**) is huge, before doing persist is there a way to check the size of the data? Is it a parameter in choosing to persist or not? Also the number of partitions (tasks) for `persist`  **> 100,000**

Comment: [Why do I have to explicitly tell Spark what to cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34117469/10938362)

Comment: the answer there is too general for me.. I'm still staring with spark and evaluating performance, so I'm looking for an answer that also considers my example and the things I mentioned, like does it help to track data input size and number of partitions in order to decide.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two cases for using `persist()`:

- After using `repartition` in order to avoid shuffling your data again and again as the dataframe is being used by the next steps. This will be useful only for the case that you call more than one action for the persisted dataframe/RDD since persist is an transformation and hence *lazily* evaluated. In general if you have multiple actions on the same dataframe/RDD.
- Iterative computations, for instance when you want to query a dataframe inside a for loop. With `persist` Spark will save the intermediate results and omit reevaluating the same operations on every action call. Another example would be appending new columns with a `join` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164274/efficient-way-of-joining-multiple-tables-in-spark).

Answer (score 2):

What my experience taught me is that you should persist the dataframe when you perform several operations on them, so you create temporal tables (also you ensure that if something fails you have a recovery point). By doing this you prevent huge DAG'S that often do not end, if you have, for example, joins. So my advice would be to do something like this:

```
# operations
df.write.saveAsTable('database.tablename_temp')
df = spark.table('database.tablename_temp')
# more operations
```

Comment: persisted replication I presume you mean to say.